# putting column to check if someone is absent or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

i have wrote query to calculate TOTAL WORK TIME and Overtime of an employee based on Intime and outTime but can't figure out to put another column 'IsAbsent'. e.g. if person doesn't come on any specific date than his INtime and TimeOut would be empty then if both are empty then new column IsAbsent should contain ABSENT otherwise if both are filled than Present.

Query:

```
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  AtdRecord t1 
INNER JOIN 
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
inner join 
      HrEmployee t3 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
group by 
          t1.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else '00:00' end, 108) as overtime
FROM times
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: well i can't figure out that how to do that, i think i can't think more

Comment: I would create a [`(scalar) function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) with an `EmplID` as parameter and check that there. Return `0/1` depending on the result and use the function in your `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I am not sure it works, but it is worth a try (It works in my head):

```
WITH times as (
SELECT    t3.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , min(t1.RecTime) AS InTime
        , max(t2.RecTime) AS [TimeOut]
        , cast(min(t1.RecTime) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
        , cast(max(t2.RecTime) as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
        , xx.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
        , CASE WHEN max(t1.EmplID) is null and max(t2.EmplID) is NULL 
                      then 'Yes' else 'No' END IsAbsent
FROM  HrEmployee t3 
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT RecDate FROM AtdRecord) xx
LEFT JOIN  AtdRecord t1 
ON    t3.EmplID = t1.EmplID 
      and t1.RecDate = xx.RecDate
LEFT JOIN
      AtdRecord t2 
ON    t3.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
AND   t2.RecDate = xx.RecDate
group by 
          t3.EmplID
        , t3.EmplName
        , xx.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else '00:00' end, 108) as overtime,
isAbsent
FROM times
```

Comment: ERROR: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column 'AtdRecord.EmplID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
Column 'AtdRecord.EmplID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Evilrising I gave it another try

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Change the order of join start with employee and left outer join with rest of the     tables and calculate time ; I tried to make it for you (fix if anything left); 
with times as (
SELECT    t1.EmplID
    , t3.EmplName
    , min(ISNULL(t1.RecTime,0)) AS InTime
    , max(ISNULL(t2.RecTime,0)) AS [TimeOut]
    , cast( min(ISNULL(t1.RecTime,0)) as datetime) AS InTimeSub
    , cast(max(ISNULL(t2.RecTime,0))  as datetime) AS TimeOutSub
    , t1.RecDate AS [DateVisited]
FROM  HrEmployee t3 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
AtdRecord t1 ON    t1.EmplID = t3.EmplID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  AtdRecord t2 
ON    t1.EmplID = t2.EmplID 
AND   t1.RecDate = t2.RecDate
AND   t1.RecTime < t2.RecTime
group by 
      t1.EmplID
    , t3.EmplName
    , t1.RecDate
)
SELECT EmplID
,EmplName
,InTime
,[TimeOut]
,[DateVisited]
,convert(char(5),cast([TimeOutSub] - InTimeSub as time), 108) totaltime
,convert(char(5), case when TimeOutSub - InTimeSub >= '08:01' then 
cast(TimeOutSub - dateadd(hour, 8, InTimeSub) as time) else '00:00' end, 108) as         overtime,
CASE WHEN InTimeSub = TimeOutSub Then 'Absent'
Else 'Present'   End As Attendance
FROM times
```

Comment: ohh ERROR: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: I don't have table structure so you can try to fix yourself; Sorry about that

Comment: Also as per example we don't have date information, I mean which Date you will show, an employee is absent as there is no record in AtdRecord table for that employee; Introduce Date Collection as well